# $\{\sin(nx)\}_n$ as a basis for $L^2[0,\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

When we look at the interval $[0,\pi)$ as an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, we know
$\{\sin(nx)\}_n$ forms a basis of $L^2(0,\pi)$ since they are the eigenfunctions of Laplacian (negative second derivative) with Dirichlet boundary condition, with eigenvalues $n^2$.

However if we look at $[0,\pi)$ as a torus, then the eigenfunctions of Laplacian with periodic boundary condition will contain a constant function, $\sin(2nx)$ and $\cos(2nx)$, in some sense this agrees with Fourier theory which is always defined on a torus instead of an interval.

My question is: the $L^2[0,\pi)$ space is different when $[0,\pi)$ is seen as an interval vs a torus, we need more functions to form a basis in the latter case. The possible causes of this could be:

1. $L^2[0,\pi)$ w.r.t. torus is a bigger space
2. $L^2[0,\pi)$ w.r.t. torus has a stronger $L^2$-norm.

But I think neither of these are true, so what is the cause of this subtle difference.

A more general question, it certainly makes sense to define a "fourier series" with only $\sin(nx)$ terms in the infinite sum when we look at $[0,\pi)$ as an interval. But why do we only care about Fourier analysis on torus?

Comment: The closure of periodic functions in $L^2[0,\pi]$ is $L^2[0,\pi]$. A condition of periodicity is not continuous with respect to the $L^2$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier looked at many types of problems associated with the heat equation. The most common types all lead to selfadjoint problems with complete orthonormal bases of eigenfunctions
\begin{align}
          & u_{xx}=\lambda u \\
         &\mbox{(periodic) } u(0)=u(\pi),\; u'(0)=u'(\pi) \\
         &\;\;\;\; 1,\cos(2nx),\sin(2nx)\\
         &\mbox{(Dirichlet) } u(0)=0=u(\pi), \\
         & \;\;\;\; \sin(nx)\\
         &\mbox{(Neumann) } u'(0)=0=u'(\pi) \\
         & \;\;\;\; 1,\cos(nx)\\
\end{align}
The first one, the periodic case, was used by Fourier to study the heat equation for a circular metal ring (torus.) All of these three generate a complete orthogonal basis for $L^2[0,\pi]$.